# Verify formatting in a number

Tags: ruby

I have a table full of numbers and need to verify if each of the number has 0 decimals and has separators',' used for '000s .

Like:  123,456

How can i verify this?

Thanks

Comment: I didn't quite understand your question. You want to know if a number has zeros after the comma in this given format?

What have you done so far?

Comment: Please provide examples with "correct" and "fail" numbers.

Comment: I have to check that all numbers >=10,000 should have no decimal places and should have separators ',' used after a set of three digits.Example: 674,456,890

Comment: Just a small clarification: You have a table full of Strings...? because numbers have no commas...

Comment: It is still unclear. It is better to provide real examples from your table and show what numbers are correct and what are not.

Comment: Sorry. Technically, yes , table full of strings.  I need to check they have the ',' inserted after every 3 digits. Correct Example: 123,456,000  Wrong : 123 456 000

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
s = '74,456,890'
if s =~ /^\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3}+)$/
   # String s has the required format
else
   # String s does not have the required format
end
```

Comment: I think it will ignore such numbers as '999,999.40'

Comment: Yea, but isn't that the goal?

Comment: Yes, the values shouldn't be having any decimal places.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that numbers are stings (because there are `,` sign):

```
numbers = [
  '100,000',
  '100,246.40',
  '100,000,304',
  '300.210',
  '10,200'
]

numbers.map { |n| n =~ /^\d{1,3},((\d{3})|(\d{3},))+$/ ? n : nil }.compact
#=> ["100,000", "100,000,304", "10,200"]
```

Comment: You solution would miss numbers smaller than 1000, such as `455`